# Tic tac toe game not learning to win

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

In this tic tac toe game using RL I penalize the agent if it does not win. The RL agent is player X. The model trains for 10'000 episodes. To determine the q values I update just the array indices for the state where the positions are available on the board, this corresponds to the function:

```
def get_valid_index(state):
    i = 0
    valid_index = []
    for a in state :          
        if a == '-' and a != 'X' and a != 'O':
            valid_index.append(i)
        i = i + 1
    return valid_index
```

I break out of the current training episode of the game is won which corresponds to "done" for the given episode:

```
if reward == 1 :
    q_table[state][action] += .1 * (reward - q_table[state][action])
    break
```

Complete code:

```
   %reset -f

import random
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval
import math

def epsilon_greedy(epsilon, state, q_table) : 

    def get_valid_index(state):
        i = 0
        valid_index = []
        for a in state :          
            if a == '-' and a != 'X' and a != 'O':
                valid_index.append(i)
            i = i + 1
        return valid_index

    def get_arg_max_sub(values , indices) : 
        i = 0
        npa = max(np.array(values)[indices])
        for ii in values : 
            if ii == npa : 
                return i
            i = i+1
        return None

    if np.random.rand() < epsilon:
        return random.choice(get_valid_index(state))
    else :
        if state not in q_table : 
            q_table[state] = np.array([0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0])
        q_row = q_table[state]
        return get_arg_max_sub(q_row , get_valid_index(state))

def make_move(current_player, current_state , q_table):
    if current_player == 'X':
        next_move = epsilon_greedy(1, current_state , q_table)
        return current_state[:next_move] + 'X' + current_state[next_move+1:]
    else : 
        next_move = epsilon_greedy(1, current_state , q_table)
        return current_state[:next_move] + 'O' + current_state[next_move+1:]

q_table = {}
max_steps = 9

def get_other_player(p):
    if p == 'X':
        return 'O'
    else : 
        return 'X'

def win_by_diagonal(mark , board):
    return (board[0] == mark and board[4] == mark and board[8] == mark) or (board[2] == mark and board[4] == mark and board[6] == mark)

def win_by_vertical(mark , board):
    return (board[0] == mark and board[3] == mark and board[6] == mark) or (board[1] == mark and board[4] == mark and board[7] == mark) or (board[2] == mark and board[5] == mark and board[8]== mark)

def win_by_horizontal(mark , board):
    return (board[0] == mark and board[1] == mark and board[2] == mark) or (board[3] == mark and board[4] == mark and board[5] == mark) or (board[6] == mark and board[7] == mark and board[8] == mark)

def win(mark , board):
    return win_by_diagonal(mark, board) or win_by_vertical(mark, board) or win_by_horizontal(mark, board)

def get_reward(player, state):
    reward = 0
    is_win = win(player , list(state))
    if is_win : 
        reward = 1
    else:
        reward = -1

    return reward

stats= []

for episode in range(0 , 10000):
    t = 0
    state = '---------'
    player = 'X'
    action = epsilon_greedy(.1 , state , q_table)
    if episode % 1000 == 0:
        print('in episode:',episode)
    while t < max_steps:

        t = t + 1

        next_state = make_move(player , state , q_table)
        next_action = epsilon_greedy(.1 , state , q_table)
        reward = get_reward('X', state)
        if reward == 1 :
            q_table[state][action] += .1 * (reward - q_table[state][action])
            break

        if next_state not in q_table : 
            q_table[next_state] = np.array([0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0])

        q_table[state][action] += .1 * (reward + (.1 * q_table[next_state][next_action]) - q_table[state][action])
        state, action = next_state, next_action

        player = get_other_player(player)

        stats.append(reward)
```

Testing the agent against a random player:

```
x_win_1 = []
o_win_0 = []
d_game = []
game_states = []
number_games = 5000

for ii in range (0 , number_games):

    if ii % 1000 == 0:
        print('In game ',ii)
        print('The number of X (trained RL algo) wins' , sum(x_win_1))
        print('The number of O (computer making random moves) wins' , sum(o_win_0))

        print('Computer RL algorithm wins' , sum(x_win_1) , 'out of total' , number_games, 'of games')
        print('Computer making random moves wins' , sum(o_win_0) , 'out of total' , number_games, 'of games')


    available_moves = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    current_game_state = '---------'

    for i in range(0 , 5):

        randomer_move = random.choice(available_moves)
        current_game_state = current_game_state[:randomer_move] + 'O' + current_game_state[randomer_move+1:]
        available_moves.remove(randomer_move)

        if i == 4 : 
            break

        computer_move_pos = epsilon_greedy(1, current_game_state, q_table)
        current_game_state = current_game_state[:computer_move_pos] + 'X' + current_game_state[computer_move_pos+1:]
        available_moves.remove(computer_move_pos)

    is_win = win('X' , list(current_game_state))   
    if is_win == True:
        x_win_1.append(1)

    is_win = win('O' , list(current_game_state))
    if is_win == True:
        o_win_0.append(1)
```

The random player approx wins double the number of games as the trained RL agent :

```
In game  0
The number of X (trained RL algo) wins 0
The number of O (computer making random moves) wins 0
Computer RL algorithm wins 0 out of total 5000 of games
Computer making random moves wins 0 out of total 5000 of games
In game  1000
The number of X (trained RL algo) wins 297
The number of O (computer making random moves) wins 592
Computer RL algorithm wins 297 out of total 5000 of games
Computer making random moves wins 592 out of total 5000 of games
In game  2000
The number of X (trained RL algo) wins 589
The number of O (computer making random moves) wins 1182
Computer RL algorithm wins 589 out of total 5000 of games
Computer making random moves wins 1182 out of total 5000 of games
In game  3000
The number of X (trained RL algo) wins 864
The number of O (computer making random moves) wins 1792
Computer RL algorithm wins 864 out of total 5000 of games
Computer making random moves wins 1792 out of total 5000 of games
In game  4000
The number of X (trained RL algo) wins 1171
The number of O (computer making random moves) wins 2369
Computer RL algorithm wins 1171 out of total 5000 of games
Computer making random moves wins 2369 out of total 5000 of games
```

Have I implemented td learning incorrectly ?

Comment: I see that you don't punish your AI for losing, you only reward him for winning. Might be important, especially since your AI is currently losing a lot of games ...

Comment: @PeterPesch  thanks, 'else:
        reward = -1'
punishes X player (agent) for losing or drawing.